HMIControlDislocatorAnimation does not work
lazarus v3.4
4 controls:

PLCTagNumber1
HMITrackBar1,set PLCTag is PLCTagNumber1, set min is 0 , set max is 100
HMIControlDislocatorAnimation1, set PLCTag is PLCTagNumber1 , set valueP0 is 0 , set valueP1 is 100 , set P0_x is 0 , set P0_y is 0, set p1_x is 100, set p1_y is 0 ,set control is HMILabel1
HMILabel1, set PLCTag is PLCTagNumber1


More context is needed. What components, any source needed to reproduce.

may be the lazarus' version is too high , U Install codecython , same code , it
does work .
